# Can't use remote server because too many open files in system

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ulimit

I'm running some python programs in the background of a remote Ubuntu machine. The program opens too many files that exceed the system limit.

I want to ssh to the remote server now, but I can't because of: `/bin/bash: Too many open files in system`

I tried `ssh -t kshi@servername.ucsd.edu 'pkill python'`, but got the same error.

How can I, now, close those background processes?

Comment: What is the output of `ulimit -a`?  Either way I imagine you have something running in the background that should not be running.

Comment: @Jesse_b The problem is that I can't even ssh to the server. I know there is a huge program running in the background, but I can't kill it.

Comment: It seems more likely that error is coming from your local machine and not the remote server

Comment: @Jesse_b The error is from the remote. I can connect to other servers without a problem.

Comment: Do you have root access to the machine?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If the problem is impossible to solve from my side, I can find the people who have root access to kill the program for me.